# TestCafe BrowserStack Environment issue when using testcafe runner

Tags: automated-tests, e2e-testing, web-testing, testcafe, browserstack

I use the "testcafe-browser.provider-browserstack" plugin for TestCafé. I try to use this in my app, but I always get a message that the login is wrong. The data is right (just "test" for this post)

```
const createTestCafe = require('testcafe');
const BrowserStack = require("testcafe-browser-provider-browserstack");

let testcafe         = null;

process.env.BROWSERSTACK_USERNAME="test";
process.env.BROWSERSTACK_PASSWORD="test";


createTestCafe('localhost', 1337, 1338)
    .then(tc => {
        testcafe     = tc;
        const runner = testcafe.createRunner();

        return runner
            .src(['tests/fixture1.js', 'tests/ingo1.js'])
            .browsers('browserstack:Chrome')
            //.browsers(['chrome'])
            .screenshots('allure/screenshots/', true)
            .reporter('allure')
            .run();
    })
    .then(failedCount => {
        console.log('Tests failed: ' + failedCount);
        testcafe.close();
    });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please use the `BROWSERSTACK_ACCESS_KEY` environment variable instead of `BROWSERSTACK_PASSWORD`. Refer to the following [article](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-browser-provider-browserstack#usage) to get details